# How do I refer to the containing type in a method on a runtime built type?

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to include a Copy method on a runtime built type that takes it's own type as a parameter - i'm sure i'm missing something obvious but i don't see how to do this

```
TypeBuilder recordTypeBuilder = 
     moduleBuilder.DefineType("_" + tableSpec.Name + "Record", TypeAttributes.Sealed,);

recordTypeBuilder.DefineMethod( "CopyFrom", MethodAttributes.Public, null, new[] { typeof( ??? ) });
```

the ???'s are where i have a problem. i can't construct the type yet, as i haven't finished creating it!

any ideas?

regards,

Comment: Can you just place `recordTypeBuilder` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TypeBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.aspx) inherits from `System.Type` and can be used in `Reflection.Emit` definitions before it has been actually created:

```
recordTypeBuilder.DefineMethod(
    "CopyFrom", MethodAttributes.Public, null, new Type[] { recordTypeBuilder });
```